# StateFlow only gets collected by one of many collectors

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

I want to notify all ViewModels in my app about the event when a user gets blocked.

My UserState:

```
    private val _refetchAllLists: MutableStateFlow<Boolean> = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val refetchAllLists: StateFlow<Boolean> = _refetchAllLists

   fun setRefetchAllLists(bool: Boolean){
        _refetchAllLists.value = bool
    }
```

Here my Repository:

```
override fun refetchAllLists(): StateFlow<Boolean> {
    return userState.refetchAllLists
}
```

and this is how I collect it inside all of my ViewModels:

```
init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.refetchAllLists().collect(){
            if(it){ 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now whenever a user gets blocked I set the MutableStateFlow Boolean to true but only one of all collectors (the one whose viewmodel gets created first) is getting notified.

Comment: What do the other collectors look like?

Comment: the last code snippet is one of those collectors, if refetchAllLists is true I simply refetch all the lists of content from the Server

Comment: Well, yeah but you say that other collectors don't work. I am asking for those.  Also "inside all of my ViewModels" What does this mean? Are you sure those view models are still alive?

Comment: Yes I am sure its still alive, all viewmodels look the same, they have the init block and inside that they collect the StateFlow

Comment: Example: My HomeViewModel is the first ViewModel that gets created, when I now switch to the ExploreScreen and the ExploreScreenViewModel gets created and I now block a user it only collects inside the HomeViewModel because thats the first collector.
If I now remove the collector of the HomeViewModel it gets collected inside the ExploreScreenViewModel.

Like I said its always the first collector that works, all the others dont

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use StateFlow as an event system, which won't work since it's conflated. I'm guessing one or more of your flows directly or indirectly sets the value back to false in its collector?

Comment: @Tenfour04 ah yes exactly.
I'm setting it back to false inside the collectors.
Didnt knew that was not possible, how should I solve this?

Comment: Is the goal to have an event that all collectors get if and only if they are subscribed at the time that the event is broadcast?

Comment: @Tenfour04 yes exactly

Comment: @Tenfour04 So basically, whenever one user reports another it calls navController.popBackStack() and somehow I need an event to notify all active viewModels to refetch the data because otherwise all data in my whole application is outdated and still contains content of the blocked user.
The Collectors who get the event should then refetch all the content of that screen. This time without the content of that blocked user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StateFlows are *conflated* which means a collector only gets the most recent value and values can be dropped if it doesn't collect it in time. Since you're setting the value back to `false` from one of the collectors, the `true` value might get dropped before the other collectors get to see it.

If your goal is to have an event that all collectors get if and only if they are subscribed at the time that the event is broadcast, then I think you can do this with a `SharedFlow<Unit>` that has no replay. We can set it to drop the oldest value since we don't care about dropped values in the event of emissions happening faster than colllection. This will allow us to use `tryEmit()` without risk of failing to emit a refresh.

```
private val _refetchAllLists: MutableSharedFlow<Unit> = 
    MutableSharedFlow(onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST)
val refetchAllLists: StateFlow<Boolean> get() = _refetchAllLists

fun triggerRefetchAllLists() {
    _refetchAllLists.tryEmit(Unit)
}
```

You might consider keeping this flow private and using it as the basis for all your other flows that need to refresh. Then you won't have to externally worry about that. If you do it this way, you should give the shared flow a `replay` of 1 to ensure there is always something initially emitted. Something like this:

```
private val refetchAllLists: MutableSharedFlow<Unit> = 
    MutableSharedFlow(replay = 1, onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST).apply {
        tryEmit(Unit) // seed with initial value
    }

// Change this:
fun getSomeRepoFlow(someId: Long): Flow<Something> =
    someApiFetch(someId)

// to this:
fun getSomeRepoFlow(someId: Long): Flow<Something> =
    refetchAllLists.flatMapLatest {
        someApiFetch(someId)
    }
```